# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') happens when i move to a different page

Tags: javascript

after the user successfully logs in, I want to navigate to a different page and export auth, however when I do so, I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') on the button, but when I remove the export auth and remove the import statement from profile.js I  don't get the error. I'm only doing this for testing purposes.

**index.html**

```
         <form>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </div>
        </form>
        <div>
            <button id="button">Login</button>
        </div>
```

**index.js**

```
// firebase configurations....


const auth = getAuth(app);
const button = document.getElementById("button");
function login() {
const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
const password = document.getElementById("password").value;

signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
        const user = userCredential.user;
        // Handle successful login here
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // Handle login error
        alert("Invalid login credentials");
    });
}
button.addEventListener("click", login);

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
        console.log("Signed In");

        // user is signed in
        const uid = user.uid;

        button.removeEventListener("click", login); // remove event lister
        // navigate to next page
        window.location.href = "/profile.html";

    } 
})

export { auth }
```

**profile.js**

```
import { auth } from "./index.js";

console.log(auth);
```

Comment: that error suggests `const button = document.getElementById("button");` results in `button` being `null` - is it?